# How to get Height and Width of background-image of an element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, selenium-webdriver, background-image

I'm trying to test an image with Selenium. But my problem is that image is `background-image` and it doesn't have `img` tag, it have this html code (it is banner from https://openweather.co.uk/products page):

```
<div class="current-img white-text half-section-right main-section-desktop"></div>
```

and [this CSS styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgSpt.png)

Is it possible to get height and width of background-image? Something like `arguments[0].width` and `arguments[0].height`?

Also when I try this code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('current-img')[0].style.backgroundImage;
```

I got `[]` - empty (like my life) result. Despite CSS styles are present (see picture attached).
Same result with:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('current-img white-text half-section-right main-section-desktop')[0].style.backgroundSize
```

When I try:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('current-img white-text half-section-right main-section-desktop')[0].style
```

I got `CSSStyleDeclaration {accentColor: '', additiveSymbols: '', alignContent: '', alignItems: '', alignSelf: '', …}` with all empty properties.

Why I got empty result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `window.getComputedStyle(yourElement)` to get the computed CSS style of the DOM element.

More about this in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

Here is an example:

```js
const element = document.getElementsByClassName('current-img white-text half-section-right main-section-desktop')[0];
const style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
// style.height is a string like this: '12px'
const height = parseInt(style.height, 10);
```

With this, you can get the backgroundSize property, but if they didn't set it explicitly and it is the default 'auto' value, you can do the following:

Get the image file used as a background, and with the following code determine the size of this image (as this will be used by auto). This is a bit tricky because you have to wait for the image to load.

```
// Get the element
const element = document.querySelector('.current-img.white-text.half-section-right.main-section-desktop')

// Get the computed style of the element
const style = window.getComputedStyle(element);

// Get the background image property
const backgroundImage = style.getPropertyValue('background-image');

// Extract the URL from the background image property
const imageUrl = backgroundImage.match(/url\(["']?([^"']*)["']?\)/)[1];

// Create an image object to load the background image
const image = new Image();
image.src = imageUrl;

// Get the image's natural width and height
image.onload = function() {
  const imageWidth = this.width;
  const imageHeight = this.height;
  
  // Use the imageWidth and imageHeight as needed
  console.log('Width:', imageWidth, 'Height:', imageHeight);
};
```

Comment: something like  `window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("background-image");` ?  Because style is "computed" I got empty properties?

Comment: @zaelcovsky Like this: `const element = document.getElementsByClassName('current-img white-text half-section-right main-section-desktop')[0]; const style = window.getComputedStyle(element);` Then you can get the height property of the style object, which will return the height as a string that you can convert

Comment: Thank you! It works, but for me it is `auto` for `.height` and `.width` properties.

Comment: @zaelcovsky I added a code snippet to my answer to help you extract the size of the used image in that case.

Comment: And why we need `[1]` at the end of `const imageUrl = backgroundImage.match(/url\(["']?([^"']*)["']?\)/)[1];`?

Comment: Big thanks to you, @tsgrgo ! Explanation is awesome and It works great also!